# How to pass create form builder in ajax redirect

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have on change ajax event, that reloads a partial, to build nested attributes, based on the selected item.

The reloaded partial looks like this(I have cut most of it since it is not important):

```
      = f.fields_for :skill_of_objects, @character.skill_of_objects.build do |ff|
        %strong
          = school_skill.skill.name_pl
        = ff.hidden_field :skill_id, value: school_skill.skill.id
        = ff.label :value
```

The problem is the `f` builder.

I have done some stack research, and based on the last answer from >> [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923939/pass-form-builder-in-remote-function-in-rails) I have ended in something like this:

```
'<%= form_for [current_user, @character] do |f| %>'
  $('#school_skills').html("<%= j render( partial: 'school_skills', locals: {f: f}) %>");
'<% end %>'
```

But I still get error like this:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0xca1eb70>:0xd0811c0>):
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated :)

Comment: you have to make a from with remote: :true and submit it on the on change event so you can pass f from form

Comment: Can you show the those file names and content of the view where you render "school_skills" ?

Comment: I have put everything thie to this problem, hope it heps :)

Answer (score 1):

My error was in the js.file

```
$('#clan_select').html("<%= j render 'character_form_clan' %>");
$('#family_select').html("<%= j render 'character_form_families' %>");
$('#school_select').html("<%= j render 'character_form_schools' %>");
$('#character_honour').html("<%= j render 'character_honour' %>");
$('#character_outfit').html("<%= j render 'character_outfit' %>");
$('#school_skills').html("<%= j render 'school_skills' %>");
$('#character_<%= @old_school_bonus %>').val('2');
$('#character_school_bonus').val('<%= @selected_school.bonus_attr %>');
$('#character_<%= @old_family_bonus %>').val('2');
$('#character_family_bonus').val('<%= @selected_family.bonus_attr %>');
$('#character_<%= @selected_family.bonus_attr %>').val('<%= @increase_val %>');
$('#character_<%= @selected_school.bonus_attr %>').val('<%= @increase_val %>');
'<%= form_for [current_user, @character] do |f| %>'
  $('#school_skills').html("<%= j render( partial: 'school_skills', locals: {f: f}) %>");
'<% end %>'
```

I have rendered school_skills twice and the second time without |f| builder.
After I have removed not second render everything works great.

```
'<%= form_for [current_user, @character] do |f| %>'
  $('#school_skills').html("<%= j render( partial: 'school_skills', locals: {f: f}) %>");
'<% end %>'
```

This part work great and it is the best way I have find so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass object as `@object` to the partial and use `fields_for` like :

```
= fields_for @object do |ff|
        %strong
          = school_skill.skill.name_pl
        = ff.hidden_field :skill_id, value: school_skill.skill.id
        = ff.label :value
```